# How to apply expression with filter and sort to IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I need apply  `Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>> expression = x=> x.Where(w => w.Quantity > 5).OrderBy(o => o.Quantity)` to any `IQueryable<T> items`. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Updated:

Some service method `GetItems` must map list of someentities to somedtos. The expression comes from client app.

```
public List<SomeDTO> GetItems(int page, int pageSize,
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<SomeDTO>,IQueryable<SomeDTO>>> dtoExpression)
{

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SomeDTO, SomeEntity>());
    var expression = Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<IQueryable<SomeDTO>, IQueryable<SomeEntity>>>>(dtoExpression);
    var items = Database.SomeEntities.FindByPage(page, pageSize, expression);

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SomeEntity, SomeDTO>());
    return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SomeEntity>, List<SomeDTO>>(items);
}
```

In DAL method `FindByPage`:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> FindByPage(int page, int pageSize, 
     Expression<Func<IQueryable<SomeEntity>, IQueryable<SomeEntity>>> expression = null)
{
    IQueryable<SomeEntity> items =
                     _db.SomeEntities.Include(a => a.SomeAnotherEntity);
    if (expression != null)
    //In this statement I need to apply expression to items
    else
      items = items.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty);
    return items.Skip((page - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}
```

Comment: Can you show sample usage?

Comment: Just updated description

Comment: Not sure why you need `Expression<Func<...>>` and not simply `Func<...>`. You can use `items = expression.Compile().Invoke(items);` but it would be simpler if the argument is `Func`.

Comment: Ivan, thank you.
Using `Func` instead `Expression` leads to several arguments (filter and sort arguments)?

Comment: I didn't mean breaking it down, my point was to use exactly the same as in your sample, just `Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>`. Just to avoid `Compile`, otherwise they are equivalent.

Comment: One big problem - you're calling Mapper.Initialize multiple times. You should call that method once per AppDomain.